# Xamarin : Build has been canceled

Tags: xamarin

I have just installed Xamarin with Visual Studio 2017 and created a new blank app.

When I hit F5 to run the app, I have the following error : Build has been canceled. But when building the solution (ctrl+shift+B), the solution builds successfully :

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>App3 -> C:\Users\xmas HP\source\repos\App3\App3\App3\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\App3.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App3.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  App3.Android -> C:\Users\xmas HP\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\bin\Debug\App3.Android.dll
2>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm really new to Xamarin. Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Here are the screenshots.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't post errors or code as images.  If you try to build the projects individually what happens?  Do some build while others fail?  What about the detailed build log - have you examined it for any specific errors?

Comment: MSB5021 means the `ToolTask` is cancelled, enable diagnostic logging for MSBuild and rebuild to obtain details. (and *do not* post errors as images).

Comment: @Json when building the solution, it builds successfully. I edited the question with the build output.

Comment: Isn't there something related to Androir Emulator ?

Comment: Please try to clean and then rebuild the solution. Then run it using a physical device.

Comment: @Thomas Carlton, did you ever resolve this? I am pulling my hair out.  Spent four days trying to create  a Hello World app.+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue.You have to enable-Enable Hyper V

First Go to Boot menu of your system then enable -Virtualization
and then follow the steps in link 
[Hyper V setup](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I already added the link which helped me to solve the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Hard drive space, Xamarin Emulator needs 2.5 GB Free space to start.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that Xamarin Messaging Center was still running in the background, even though vs was closed.  I killed all tha xamarin processes in task manager restarted visual studio and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Following steps helped me:

1. Open Tools-> Android->Andorid Device Manager
2. Select the emulator and click "Edit".
3. Find "hw.gpu.mode" in Properties. By default the value was "auto".
4. Change it to "off".
5. Start the emulator.

PS: The Hyper-V should be enabled.
Thanks.